# Code not working, expecting program to print, but nothing is printed

Tags: python, function

I have a file `main.py` containing this:

```py
import misc

def do_meme(self, raw_args):
    misc.memes()

do_meme("hello world")
```

and a file `misc.py` containing this:

```py
import random

def bitch_lasanga_func():
    print("""
  Now playing: Bitch Lasagna
  1:07  ●━━━━━━───────  2:15
  ⇆ㅤㅤㅤ◁ㅤㅤ❚❚ㅤㅤ▷ㅤㅤㅤ↻
    """)

memes_list = {
    "bitch_lasanga":bitch_lasanga_func,
}

def memes():
    memes_list[random.choice(list(memes_list))]
```

When i run the file `main.py` i would expect the output to be this:

```
   Now playing: Bitch Lasagna
   1:07  ●━━━━━━───────  2:15
   ⇆ㅤㅤㅤ◁ㅤㅤ❚❚ㅤㅤ▷ㅤㅤㅤ↻
```

But instead i don't get anything. Can anyone help me debug?

NOTE: Full project [here](https://repl.it/@TacoCode/Code-demo)

Comment: Should you have something like this: `memes_list[random.choice(list(memes_list))]()` ? the paraenthesis at the end to execute the method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `memes` just outputs the function `bitch_lasanga_func` (typo btw) without calling it. You have to call it with `()`.

```
def memes():
    memes_list[random.choice(list(memes_list))]()
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! And thanks for mentioning the typo!